# Dimension issues for LSTM sequence model on Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, multiclass-classification

I'd like to train a simple LSTM model for sequence data with 128 time steps with  6 features for 118 multi-classes.

The dimensions of the dataset are shown below:

```
X_train, X_test shape: (batch, timesteps, num_features) = (batch, 128, 6)
y_train, y_test shape: (batch, 118)
```

where labels are represented by one-hot encoding with 118 classes.

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 32, kernel_initializer = 
    tf.initializers.zeros()),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 6)
])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data = (X_test, y_test), epochs=20, verbose=0)
```

There is an error below after executing the code above:

`ValueError: Shapes (None, 118) and (None, 6) are incompatible`

How to fix the dimension issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [units](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense#:%7E:text=Args-,units,-Positive%20integer%2C%20dimensionality) parameter in `tf.keras.layers.Dense()` is the dimensionality of the output space.

Since you have used 6 units in the last dense layer, the model will process the input and return a tensor of shape `(None, 6)` and compare it with the labels of shape `(None, 118)`, which would be incompatible.

Try changing the number of units to 118 in the last dense layer to get a compatible model.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because your network will output a vector of size 6, while your expected output is 118. so You have two ways.
1- You can change ur "tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 6)" to "tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 118)"

2- you can add one more dense layer to reshape the output to 118. so the final model will be

> model = keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 32,
> kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.zeros()),
> tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 6),tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 118)])

Another issue you might face is the None at the shape. I'm not sure why but u might need to check the data or something.